# Update Multiple Documents Using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection of documents like following schema

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'),
    name: "abc",
    value: 1.11,
    otherField1: "def",
    otherField2: "ghi"
},
{
    _id: ObjectId('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'),
    name: "def",
    value: 2.15,
    otherField1: "jkl",
    otherField2: "abc"
}
```

I am calling an API which gives me result like this

```
{
    name: "abc",
    newValue: 3.12
},
{
    name: "def",
    newValue: 5.16
}
```

Now I have to update all documents with their new values by matching name field. One way is to run a loop on result and use mongoose's findOneAndUpdate function. Is there any other way where I don't need to run a loop and can update all documents using only single query.

Note: name field is unique in collection

Please also note that I am updating documents' "value" field using "newValue" field from the result of the API

Comment: Can you show your query please?

Comment: function updateRecords(req, res) {
    req.body.forEach(function(element, index) {
        MyModel.findOneAndUpdate({"name": element.name}, {"value": element.newValue})
            .then(function() {
                console.log("Record Updated");
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
    });
    return res.status(200).send({success: true, data: "Records Updated"});
}